# Does ubuntu reinstall preserve the mount points?

Tags: mount, 14.10, reinstall

I am trying to reinstall ubuntu 14.10 after it tried updating to it from 14.04, failed and the GUI stopped working. (I suspect it has to do with it overwriting the graphics configuration and not being able to start unity, but I am out of time for troubleshooting.)

After downloading the distribution DVD and following other answers to make it display something beyond the boot menu, the simple question I have is:

I have a copy of etc/fstab, but does ubuntu preserve the mount points if I choose the option "Reinstall Ubuntu 14.10 - Documents, music and other personal files will be kept *where possible*."?

(Just wondered if anybody knew as I cannot risk my data to find out.)

Answer (score 0):

To be safe, you could copy it to your home directory, since that will certainly be kept intact if you choose to reinstall.